# Delayed subtask in django-celery

Tags: celery, django-celery

This is my code:

```
add.apply_async((1, 2), countdown=5, link=delete.subtask())
```

How can I add a custom delay on **delete subtask** passing the result of the add task as a parameter?

Is it possible with this syntax/format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've found the solution

> add.apply_async((1, 2), countdown=2, link=delete.subtask((), countdown=10))